# is there a way to load react app in popup using angular?

Tags: angular, reactjs

I have angular app and react app for now I make a simple redirection from angular app to react app.
Has there been a way to load the react app in a popup inside the angular app?
or
how can I open the react app in small tap?  (like when you have to login with google account it opens a small tap then when you finish login it get back to the app with the token).
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean in a new browser window, or in a modal? In a browser window, you are in a completely new environment, so you can just load your app. If a modal, you are in the same environment, so you'd need to ensure react and angular are not going to interfere with each other - then you can load your app as remote content (not a angular dev, but I'm sure there's a way to load a remote page into a div). Worst case you can always revery to an iframe if you have to.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer and  yes in a model